# laravel - login redirect loses the url hash

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, authentication

When I want to share a page url from my site like `mysite.com/page1#foo=bar`, or want to visit this page when I am logged out, I am redirected to the `login` form as `page1` route is in the `auth middleware`.

My problem is that after I log in successfully, I am redirected to `mysite.com/page1` and I lose the hash value.

(the hash value is also not kept on the `/login`)

Is there any easy way provided by Laravel to keep the hash ?
As the hash is not sent to server, I kind of doubt it, but maybe there is something I missed somewhere !

Otherwise I would need to overwrite the login, maybe read the hash with JS and somehow re-inject it in the redirect after login, but would quite like to avoid doing that if there is an easy way :)

Comment: Yeah I was just about to say that the `#fragment` isn't sent to the server. Since the middleware kicks in and redirects you before you're able to execute any client side code, I'm not sure how you would go about doing it. The way to get around it I think would be to remove the middleware and use JS to pass the fragment to the server when you detect that you need to redirect.

Comment: Alternatively, you could possibly change the `auth` middleware so that it doesn't redirect, and instead returns a view, in which you can then add your client side code, preserve the fragment and then perform the redirect using JS.

Comment: sounds like a good approach ! I will investigate and try to find a way to do that ! If I can get to `/login#foo=bar` I should be good to go !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Mruf direction, I managed to get to the bottom of this.
Not sure it is the best implementation, but it seems to be working.

Basically, I insert the hash value in the form as Mruf suggested, and then extended the `handleUserWasAuthenticated` function in `AuthController`

**login.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.urlHash').val(window.location.hash);
  });
</script>

<form id="login-form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control urlHash" name="urlHash" value="">
  ....
</form>
```

**AuthController.php**

```
protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
        return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
    }

    // old code: return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());

    $newRequest = redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    $newRequest->setTargetUrl($newRequest->getTargetUrl() . $request->urlHash);

    return $newRequest;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple JavaScript would do the trick:

```
$("#login-form").submit(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='hash' value='"+window.location.hash+"'");

    $(this).submit();
});
```

Now you can access the hash within your request object

```
function controllerAction(Request $request){
    $hash = $request->get("hash");
    // Parse Hash
    ....
    // Redirect to somewhere
    ....
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing similar, but that is only 50% of the process I think. Your solution would imply that I am on `/login#foo=far` which I am not. Once I got there though, your solution should do the trick !

Comment: Looks like I confused myself testing different url. It looks like it is actually redirecting to `/login#foo=bar`, so as it keeps the hash I should be able to test your solution !

Comment: another solution would be `$(window).on('hashchange',function(){//submit hash with ajax to server});` so always when the hash is changed you submit it to the server and persist in in the session. It is untested, so...